# Wrong string library after dlopen?

Tags: c++, string, dlopen

im currently using dlopen on a modular program and I think something is really wrong, but I cant seem to figure it out.

requirementData is a vector of a class called VoidData. It's simply a class to handle void* easily

getCopyOfData() uses memcpy to copy the data stored in the void*. Until here everthing is fine, the address of *voidptr* is different from the one stored in my VoidData object so the copy was a success.

Now... *stringA* gives me the right string. This is also okay for *stringB*. But then comes stringC and he gives me something weird.

```
void* voidptr = requirementData[0].getCopyOfData();

string stringA = *((string*) voidptr);
cout << "VoidPtr: " << stringA << endl; // VoidPtr: 'SayHey'

string stringB = *((string*) voidptr);
cout << "VoidPtr: " << stringB << endl; // VoidPtr: 'SayHey'

// load library
void *handle = dlopen("/usr/lib64/libOpcWorkingPackage.so", RTLD_LAZY);

string stringC = *((string*) voidptr);
cout << "VoidPtr: " << stringC << endl; // VoidPtr: '����'
```

I also tried to cast *voidptr* to an array of uint8_t. Every time the array gives me the same 32 numbers.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(stringC); i++){
    cout << to_string(((uint8_t*) voidptr)[i]) << ", ";
}
cout << endl;
// 80, 181, 228, 245, 255, 127, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 97, 121, 101, 119, 121, 0, 0, 0, 183, 228, 245, 255, 127, 49, 52
```

Im out of ideas, maybe somebody can help me.

Thanks, Narase

Edit: Here's my getCopyOfData() function:

```
void* VoidData::getCopyOfData() const {
    void *data = malloc(size);
    memcpy(data, storedData, size);
    return data;
}
```

Edit: Got it

The data I get are a char[]. This char[] is put in a string which doesnt copy them, it just puts a pointer on it. After the char[] is released, the string works until the memory issnt used anymore after that

Thank you for the correct idea user4581301!

Comment: Need to see `getCopyOfData`. Very likely it is returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: While I'm not sure this is exactly your problem, there is a code smell in your code because all strings stringA, stringB, and stringC will try to free voidptr when they go out of scope. It could be the compiler is inserting a call to stringA / stringB's destructor before dlopen is called, so that at the final call to cout voidptr has been freed (twice) and you are printing out freed memory.

Comment: My guess was wrong. Now I think the source string is long dead by the time the `VoidData` is being used. No way to prove this without seeing a lot more code. [mcve] please.

Comment: But this pops up a horrible code smell. Danger-danger-danger! You cannot memcpy a `std::string`. It is not trivially copyable. `std::string` does not always contain the string data. It usually contains a pointer to the data. This will not be fully respected by `memcpy` and leave you with effectively two `std::string`s pointing to the same data. Either string `string` can now totally screw over the other `string`

Comment: Well, in the output of the array, there is the containing string data ('83, 97, 121, 101, 119, 121') and I can call it as often as I want, its always the correct output until I call `dlopen()`.

Comment: Also my debugger shows me, that even after stringC was created and printed, stringA and stringB are good. Btw I found something... when I call `dlopen()` with the RTD_NOLOAD flag, stringC is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data I get is in a char[]. This char[] is put in a string (by me) which doesnt copy them, it just puts a pointer on it. After the char[] is released, the string works until the memory issnt used anymore after that.

Thank you for the correct idea user4581301!